# UITableView Selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a grouped UITableView and right now when I select multiple items in that table it will highlight blue. **Is there a way to change the highlight color to a checkmark?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You have to manipulate these properties of `UITableViewCell` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
// when the cell is first created
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

// when configuring the cell (after checking your variable if it is selected)
cell.accessoryType = (selected) ? 
    UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

One scheme could be to have a variable that holds the selected indexPath, or just a number if you have only one section. You could also get a reference to the cell in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and set it there, but I have found the other scheme to be more robust because you need to unset the checkmark in the previously selected cell.

Comment: missed 'Cell': UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set `cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor`. but you will need to check is it checked or not in -tableView:cellForIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Its undocumented feature (not sure if Apple will accept), but it works:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    [self.tableView setValue:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:@"multiselectCheckmarkColor"];       
}
```